# Hibernate update specific entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is the entity model I want to save (create/update):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class EventEntity {

    @Column(name = "NATURE")
    private String nature;

    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @Column(name = "NOTIFIED", insertable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Boolean notified;

    // Getter - Setter - Builder
}
```

There are two ways to update this entity:

- The first one to update all attributes except the `notified` attribute
- The second one to update the `notified` attribute only

Is there a way to tell Hibernate to ignore some fields for a specific method?
Do I need to create two different specific dao methods?
Do I need to keep `updatable=false` for a classic `save` method and create a custom one to update the `notified` attribute only? Best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to do it separately.

- For the first update (all fields but *notified*) I would indeed use the `updatable = false` which tells hibernate not to include the field in the SQL statement. This way you just have to call tha save() method.
- For the second update (only the *notified* field), Make a custom query :

  ```
  @Modifying
  @Query("UPDATE EventEntity e SET e.notified = ?2 WHERE e.id = ?1")
  @Transactional
  void customUpdate(UUID itemId, boolean notified);
  ```

  (Assuming the condition is an ID)

This should work the way you need. Hope that helps.